# battery charging problem

Tags: 14.04, battery, boot

My problem reappeared again.

I have a Lenovo G780 which originally came with Windows 8 installed, and its power management would charge the battery up to 60%, but Windows crashed, and it was replaced with Ubuntu 14.04. If the battery drains to 0%, I can't boot up the system.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear, so when the battery drains 0% and I plug the power the pc won't boot.

Answer (score 0):

Draining the battery to 0% charge likely will cause any laptop with any OS to fail to boot. Recharge it completely, and then boot up.

And, since you're new here, please make sure to select the best answer provided and click on that answer's checkmark so they get the gratification of knowing they helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a laptop hardware issue, not an ubuntu issue.  I will explain.  Generally speaking, Lenovos are the most well supported of all brands of computers when it comes to all distributions of Linux, so I would be very surprised if it were say, a matter of a driver.

Now if you open, [this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Lenovo%20G780&oq=Lenovo%20G780&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=Lenovo%20G780%20charging%20issue), you will find that quite a few people share your exact complaint, practically word for word.  When I did this search, I even found one hit, the fourth I believe, which indicated it had been solved, though I admit having opened that hit I can't claim I'm clear about the solution.

Either way, it looks as though the problem may be due to an ACPI device driver, cmos setting, or even bios flaw which can be solved by means of an update to your bios. If I were you I'd carefully inspect my acpi settings in my cmos settings.  I might try taking the battery out and putting it back in.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear, so when the battery drains 0% and I plug the power the pc won't boot. I think there is some problem there, Most likely there is some logic error, if no battery but there is ac power it should boot.